# Selecting from group based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result set ClusterTests:

```
+--------+---------+------------+-------------+
| TestId | Cluster | TestDate   | TestResult  |
+--------+---------+------------+-------------+
|      1 | A       | 2019-01-01 | Accepted    |
|      2 | A       | 2019-01-15 | Rejected    |
|      3 | B       | 2019-01-01 | Accepted    |
|      4 | B       | 2019-01-15 | Accepted    |
+--------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

'
I would like to select for each month and each cluster, the newest test that is accepted. For the above result set the desired result would be:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| Cluster | Month   | TestId     |
+---------+---------+------------+
| A       | 2019-01 | 1          |
| B       | 2019-01 | 4          |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

So far what I have is :

```
select Cluster,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), TestDate, 120) as Month,
       Max(TestId) as TestId
from ClusterTests
group by CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), TestDate, 120),
         Cluster
```

However this just retrieves the latest test for each month:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| Cluster | Month   | TestId     |
+---------+---------+------------+
| A       | 2019-01 | 2          |
| B       | 2019-01 | 4          |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

Any help in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: check out `row_number()`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (
                SELECT      TestId,Cluster,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), TestDate, 120) as Month,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Cluster,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), TestDate, 120) Order By TestDate Desc) as RowNo
                FROM        ClusterTests
                WHERE       TestResult  = 'Accepted'
            ) result
WHERE       result.RowNo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple where filter on subquery will do the job. Since in your query you're getting records for `rejected` also whereas you need to filter them only for `accepted`.

```
select Cluster,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), TestDate, 120) as Month,
       Max(TestId) as TestId
from (select TestId ,Cluster ,TestDate ,TestResult  from ClusterTests 
      where TestResult = 'Accepted') as tab 
group by CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), TestDate, 120),
         Cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

With a CTE and NOT EXISTS:

```
with cte as (
  select cluster, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), TestDate, 120) Month, testid 
  from ClusterTests 
  where testresult = 'Accepted'
)
select c.* from cte c
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where cluster = c.cluster and testid > c.testid and month = c.month
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=979cc0c5ea0992226e8c277248c145d7).
Results:

```
> cluster | Month   | testid
> :------ | :------ | -----:
> A       | 2019-01 |      1
> B       | 2019-01 |      4
```